# post a $_GET variables from url

Tags: post, get

Is there a way to post a $_GET value from a url.
As the $_GET value is actually part of the form details that I want to post to the database.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean here. Can you specify a language (I'm guessing PHP?) along with an example of the form and any code you currently have?

Comment: yes,in php. Example the url :people.php?name=Joe. i want to post the name value which is joe to my database.